# Can I access specific key values in dictionary from django template?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Is there any get() function for this instead?

```
{% for key, value in choices.items %} 
  <li>{{key}} - {{value}}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

From python I have the get() function to get values from a specific key. But I couldn't find a corresponding way to do that with django template tags. So I wonder is it possible?
I need to get specific values since using loops adds a lot of new lines in the html source.

Or should take care of the output inside the view before sending it out to the template, which method is better?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `{{ choices.items.key }}` to access a specific dict element.

There is no reason to care about whitespace in the HTML code though; the typical end-user has no real business in reading it and if he's curious he an always use a DOM viewer or run it through a HTML beautifier.

Comment: yes, that's true. It is just that I get a bit annoyed seeing that it looks untidy ^^;

Comment: you can't do the former (`choices.items['key']`) with django's template language

Comment: I'll have to try jinja out so - that sounds useful

Answer (score 4):

If you want a specific value, just add it to the dotted-path:

```
{{ choices.items.somekey }}
```

will get you the value of `choices.items['somekey']` if `choices.items` is a `dict`.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are way advance now, just to share my point. you could do this way as well

```
{% for value in dict %} 
    {{value}}                                                                   
{% endfor %}
```

or with key, value like

```
{% for key,value in dict.items %}
    {{key}} : {{ value }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

If choices type is DICT like {}.

```
{{choices.somekey|default:""}}
```

If choices.items is DICT type.

```
{{choices.items.somekey|default:""}}
```

Try See little example.

```
# In Views.py
def dict_test(request):
    my_little_dict = {"hi": "Hello"} 
    ....
# in Template
{{my_little_dict.hi}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify as `{{ choices.key_name }}`
It worked for me. Just simple

Answer (score 0):

```
{{ choices.values }}
```

This gives you a list of all the values in the dictionary at once.