# Django template displaying key and values for the {% forloop%} : How to iterate over a dictionary in a template?

Tags: django, django-templates

I have this value in my views.py

```
values = {"Name":"Mark","Contact":"799865","Message":"Something Here", .... ,"ValueN":"TextN.."}

variables = RequestContext(request, {"values":values)

t = loader.get_template('do.html')
```

Now In my do.html I did this..

{% for key, value in values %}
        {{ key }} = {{ value }}
    {% endfor %}

But I got this in the display of my do.html:

```
v = p v = p v = p T = i v = p v = p v = p v = p v = p v = p v = p v = p v = p v = p v = p v = p v = p .... v = p v = p v = p
```

My question now is, how can I display using the forloop in the do.html so that it will look like this

```
Name = Mark
Contact = 799865
....
to the end of the loop
```

what Im I doing is, I am trying to convert my code in php to python django template

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
    if (strlen($value) > 0) {
             <input type="text" name="<?=$key?>" value="<?=$value?>"/><br>
        }
}
```

does it possible in the django template that I will be not using an specific key to load it just like this `{{ choices.items.key }}` ?

Answer (score 0):

So your question is "How to iterate over a dictionary in a template?", right? I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9915370/can-i-access-specific-key-values-in-dictionary-from-django-template) solution solves your problem!