# Accessing Specific Dictionary Values by Key in Django Template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I know to use '.' notation to access dictionary items in a template (just like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9915370/can-i-access-specific-key-values-in-dictionary-from-django-template) explained), but when I try to access a particular key, it's not working. What's going wrong?

My dictionary:
`images[mykey] = "the value string"`

Then in the template, I try to access by key but it doesn't work:

```
{% for x in otherdict %}
    {{ x }}
    {{ images.items.x }}
{% endfor %}
```

I can loop through the `images` dict just fine though:

```
{% for k,v in images.items %}
    {{ k }} -- {{ v }}
{% endfor %}
```

but I need to access by specific key!

Comment: Your dict doesn't have an element named "x".

Comment: "x" is a key of the dict....since it's a variable, how do I make that work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do that out of the box, but you can do with a custom template tag.

Please see this old Django ticket for a possible solution, and for the reason the idea got rejected:[Accessing dict values via a value of a variable as key](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/12486)

Comment: oooh ok, I didn't realize that- spent way too long trying to make it work the way I had it. Finally just ended up looping through the dict each time to find the key. Thank you so much @Roodie !

Answer (score 0):

Very late to this party, but this might help somebody anyway. It doesn't need a template tag. You can very easily define a class that will let Django Template language do the job.

```
class DotDict( dict):
    def __getattr__( self, attr):
        return self[attr] # or, return self.get( attr, default_value)
```

This is a dict in all aspects except that you can't usefully use `setattr` on it, because `getattr` is redefined to return the same as indexing it. Which means that in a Django template, you can do

```
{{dotdict.x}}
```

(the template engine catches KeyError and quietly returns the blank string, if you don't use `.get` to provide a default)

You can convert an ordinary dict to a DotDict using the standard dict's init method

```
dotdict = DotDict( ordinary_dict)
```

which might be useful when defining a context for rendering.

You can inherit from `Counter` or other dict-like objects instead of plain `dict`, if you desire.